# Updating release field with Rally API fails, what's wrong and how to fix it?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to update some release fields with the Rally API, but the requests fails when trying to save, I've tried with normal and custom fields. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here's my portion of the code that attempts to do this:

```
launch: function() {
        this._getReleaseModel().then({
            success: function(model) {
                console.log('release model: ', model)
                return this._getReleaseRecord(model, 72984315568);
            },
            scope: this
        }).then({
            success: function(releaseRecord) {
                console.log('release record:', releaseRecord);
                this._updateReleaseRecord(releaseRecord, 'Name', 'Test Release Modified by API');
            },
            scope: this
        });
}

_getReleaseModel: function() { // returns model promise
        return Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
           type: 'Release'
        });
},

_getReleaseRecord: function(model, objectID) { // returns record promise
        return model.load(objectID);
},

_updateReleaseRecord: function(record, fieldToChange, newField) {
        console.log('gonna update this record:', record);
        record.set(fieldToChange, newField);

        record.save({
            callback: function(result, operation) {
                if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                    console.log('record saved successfully');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('failed to save record');
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Note I'm not pasting the whole app code for simplicity. Thank you.

Comment: that code all looks good... can you post what errors you're getting from wsapi and/or the js console?

Comment: That's the weird thing, I'm not getting any errors neither from wsapi or the js console. All I get is the "failed to save record" console statement that I included in the else statement of the save function. That's why I posted the question, since I couldn't find any other way to debug. Can it be because of some of my user permissions?

Comment: By the way, I don't know if this could be the cause of the problem too, but I am testing this from the app.debug through cloud9. I'm gonna test this code in an actual custom app inside rally to see if it works there.

Comment: Yeap, that was the problem. Apparently save doesn't work when testing from the cloud9 server. Going to post answer. I wonder if there is any way to actually make it work from outside rally, like when testing through cloud9?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that I was testing the rally code from a cloud9 server through app-debug.html. Apparently the save method can't access the Rally CA central from outside rally. I tested the code inside an actual rally custom html app and it worked fine. Thanks to Kyle for answering promptly either way.

Comment: Strange- I've definitely used cloud9 in the past, but maybe only for reads and not writes...